# Elementary OS closing all apps after locked for a long period

Tags: release-hera, suspend, apps, lock

I've been having a problem for about 3 months now: after a few hours with the screen locked, when I login I find all apps closed. Even the dock is closed.

If it is for an hour or less (I have not chronometered this) it does not happen.

I am using Hera, fully updated to the latest package.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably when it stays locked for long times it logs out, that is why when you unlock, you actually login again.

Play around with the Power settings in System Settings, to configure it properly.
Look for the time setting in Suspend when inactive section.

[image]